# Почему тест выдает не верный id?

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

Пытаюсь тестировать класс **Contactor**. Тесты проваливаются.
Создаю один экземпляр класса, вызываю метод *test_get_id*, должен возвращать 1, а возвращает 2.
Но при этом все тесты проходят если убрать метод *test_get_characteristics*.

```
class User(ABC):
    id: int = 0

    global characteristic_list
    characteristic_list = []

    count = 0

    @classmethod
    def incr(self):
        self.count += 1
        return self.count

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = self.incr()

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    def add_characteristic(self, name, type, question):
        characteristic_list.append(Characteristic(name, type, question))

    def get_characteristics(self):
        return characteristic_list


class Contactor(User):
    pass


### test

class TestContractor(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.contactor1 = Contactor()


    def test_get_id(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.contactor1.get_id(), 1)


    def test_get_characteristics(self):
        self.contactor1.add_characteristic("Имя", "str", "Как тебя зовут?")
        self.contactor1.add_characteristic("Фамилия", "str", "Какая у тебя фамилия?")
        self.contactor1.add_characteristic("Возраст", "int", "Сколько тебе лет?")

        self.assertEqual(len(self.contactor1.get_characteristics()), 3)
```

Подскажите, почему так происходит? Как мне от этого избавиться?
Такое ощущение, что конструктор вызывается по несколько раз.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `incr` вызывается каждый раз при создании экземпляра класса.
А `setUp` вызывается для каждого теста. Т.е. создает `self.contactor1` столько раз, сколько есть тестов в классе `TestContractor`. Вы не можете для такого класса проверять статично id в тестах, если их больше одного, если `Contactor` создается под каждый тест. Надо использовать метод `setUpClass`. Он выполняется один раз для всех тестов в тестируемом классе.

```
class TestContractor(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls) -> None:
        cls.contactor1 = Contactor()

    def test_get_id(self) -> None:
        self.assertEqual(self.contactor1.get_id(), 1)

    def test_get_characteristics(self) -> None:
        self.contactor1.add_characteristic("Имя", "str", "Как тебя зовут?")
        self.contactor1.add_characteristic("Фамилия", "str", "Какая у тебя фамилия?")
        self.contactor1.add_characteristic("Возраст", "int", "Сколько тебе лет?")

        self.assertEqual(len(self.contactor1.get_characteristics()), 3)
```

Comment: как мне атрибут класса id переделать в экземпляр класса?

Comment: @DmitriyBegishev Поправил свой ответ и добавил код с рабочими тестами.